# how I can write more than one jpg image to Dicom file Using Dcm4che3?

Tags: java, dicom

In previous question I asked before a while,I could write one image to Dicom,but now I need to write two or more jpg images in frames as sequence in Dicon file.Using dcm4che3.Please can anyone help ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Attributes attrs = new Attributes();
    String ts = UID.JPEG2000;
    Attributes fmi = Attributes.createFileMetaInformation("1.2.3", UID.MRImageStorage , ts);
    File f = new File("/tmp/taylor.jpg");
    BufferedImage vf = ImageIO.read(f);
    attrs.setString(Tag.PatientName, VR.AE, "Test");
    attrs.setString(Tag.PatientSex, VR.CS, "M");
    attrs.setString(Tag.PatientID, VR.CS, "10");
    attrs.setString(Tag.PatientBirthDate, VR.AS, "19861010");
    attrs.setString(Tag.StudyDate, VR.AS, "20140126");
    attrs.setString(Tag.SeriesDate, VR.AS, "20140126");
    attrs.setString(Tag.StudyTime, VR.AS, "101010");
    attrs.setString(Tag.SeriesTime, VR.AS, "101010");
    attrs.setString(Tag.StudyDescription, VR.AS, "Test #1");
    attrs.setString(Tag.SeriesDescription, VR.AS, "Test #2");
    attrs.setString(Tag.Modality, VR.CS, "MR");
    attrs.setInt(Tag.Columns, VR.US, vf.getWidth());
    attrs.setInt(Tag.Rows, VR.US, vf.getHeight());
    attrs.setInt(Tag.InstanceNumber, VR.US, 1);
    attrs.setInt(Tag.SamplesPerPixel, VR.IS, 3);
    attrs.setString(Tag.PhotometricInterpretation, VR.CS, "MONOCHROME2");
    attrs.setInt(Tag.BitsAllocated, VR.IS, 8);
    attrs.setInt(Tag.BitsStored, VR.IS, 8);
    attrs.setInt(Tag.NumberOfFrames, VR.IS, 5);
    attrs.setInt(Tag.SeriesNumber, VR.IS, 2);


    DataBufferByte buff = (DataBufferByte) vf.getData().getDataBuffer();
    Fragments fr = attrs.newFragments(Tag.PixelData, VR.OW, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fr.add(buff.getData(0));
    }
    attrs.trimToSize();
    File fi = new File("/tmp/test.dcm");
    System.out.println(fi.getCanonicalPath());
    System.out.println(fmi);
    System.out.println(attrs);
    DicomOutputStream dos = new DicomOutputStream(fi);
    dos.writeDataset(fmi, attrs);
    dos.finish();
    dos.close();
}
```

This code is create the dcm file but i could not open it with Weasis viewer .

Answer (score 0):

Using What I gave you [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087778/how-to-write-jpg-image-to-dicom-file-using-dcm4che3/21134015#21134015) you would loop over all you jpg images and concatenate the bytes together. Set the concatenated bytes to be the pixel data.

Then add

```
 attribs.setInt(Tag.NumberOFFrames, VR.**, numberOfImages);
```

to the dicom header. I can't recall what the VR of this Tag should be so check the DICOM standard for that.

**Edit 1**

I would set the pixel data as

```
    byte[] buffbytes = buff.getData(0);
    byte[] b = new byte[5*buff.getData(0).length];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(buffbytes, 0, b, i*buffbytes.length, buffbytes.length);
    }

    attrs.setBytes(Tag.PixelData, VR.OW, b);
```

Comment: Thnx for your help again,, I tried what you did suggest ,but i got a java.io.EOFException ,did you tried it by yourself?

Comment: I've done something similar many times before. Could you post your code please in your question?

Comment: I got this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Raster ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 1177 height = 995 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 0 is incompatible with ColorModel ColorModel: #pixelBits = 8 numComponents = 1 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@142ea9b transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false