# images rgb jpg to dicom with dcm4che3

Tags: java, jpeg, dicom, dcm4che

I used the solution proposed by medPhys-pl, [solution jpg to dicom with dcm4che3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087778/how-to-write-jpg-image-to-dicom-file-using-dcm4che3/).

I try convert file jpg to file dicom. when jpg is monochrome my code is sucessful, however if the file jpg is RGB, the file dicom has colours changed regards to original image.

Somebody knows the reason???

thanks

```
    File fileJpg = new File(path + "tmp_" + numImagen + ".jpg");
    File fileDicomFinal = new File(path + "tmp_" + numImagen + ".dcm");
    File fileDicomOrig = new File(cabeceraOriginal);
    File fileDicomTipo = new File(cabeceraTipo);

    BufferedImage jpg = ImageIO.read(fileJpg);

    //Convert the image to a byte array
    DataBufferByte buff = (DataBufferByte) jpg.getData().getDataBuffer();
    byte[] buffbytes = buff.getData(0);
    byte[] b = new byte[5*buff.getData(0).length];
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        System.arraycopy(buffbytes, 0, b, j*buffbytes.length, buffbytes.length);
    }

    //Copy a header 
    DicomInputStream dis = new DicomInputStream(fileDicomTipo);
    Attributes meta = dis.readFileMetaInformation();
    Attributes attribs = dis.readDataset(-1, Tag.PixelData);
    dis.close();
    DicomInputStream disOrig = new DicomInputStream(fileDicomOrig);
    Attributes attribsOrig = disOrig.readDataset(-1, Tag.PixelData);
    disOrig.close();

    //get properties of image
    int colorComponents = jpg.getColorModel().getNumColorComponents();
    int bitsPerPixel = jpg.getColorModel().getPixelSize();
    int bitsAllocated = (bitsPerPixel / colorComponents); 
    int samplesPerPixel = colorComponents; 

    //Change the rows and columns
    attribs.setString(Tag.SpecificCharacterSet, VR.CS, "ISO_IR 100");  
    attribs.setString(Tag.PhotometricInterpretation, VR.CS, samplesPerPixel == 3 ? "RGB" : "MONOCHROME2"); 

    attribs.setInt(Tag.SamplesPerPixel, VR.US, samplesPerPixel);           
    attribs.setInt(Tag.Rows, VR.US, jpg.getHeight());  
    attribs.setInt(Tag.Columns, VR.US, jpg.getWidth());  
    attribs.setInt(Tag.BitsAllocated, VR.US, bitsAllocated);  
    attribs.setInt(Tag.BitsStored, VR.US, bitsAllocated);  
    attribs.setInt(Tag.HighBit, VR.US, bitsAllocated-1);  
    attribs.setInt(Tag.PixelRepresentation, VR.US, 0); 

    /*Also, our Dicom header needs information about date and time of creation:*/
    attribs.setDate(Tag.InstanceCreationDate, VR.DA, new Date());  
    attribs.setDate(Tag.InstanceCreationTime, VR.TM, new Date());  
    /* Every Dicom file has a unique identifier. 
    * Here we’re generating study, series and Sop instances UIDs. 
    * You may want to modify these values, but you should to care about their uniqueness. 
    */
    attribs.setString(Tag.SeriesInstanceUID, VR.UI, UIDUtils.createUID();  
    attribs.setString(Tag.SOPInstanceUID, VR.UI, UIDUtils.createUID());  
    attribs.setString(Tag.StudyInstanceUID, VR.UI, UIDUtils.createUID());
    attribs.setString(Tag.AccessionNumber, VR.IS, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.AccessionNumber));
    attribs.setString(Tag.PatientName, VR.CS, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.PatientName));
    attribs.setString(Tag.InstitutionName, VR.CS, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.InstitutionName));
    attribs.setString(Tag.PatientID, VR.CS, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.PatientID));
    attribs.setString(Tag.PatientBirthDate, VR.DT, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.PatientBirthDate));
    attribs.setString(Tag.PatientSex, VR.CS, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.PatientSex));
    attribs.setString(Tag.OtherPatientIDs, VR.CS, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.OtherPatientIDs));
    attribs.setString(Tag.PatientAge, VR.AS, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.PatientAge));
    attribs.setString(Tag.AcquisitionDateTime, VR.DT, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.AcquisitionDateTime));
    attribs.setString(Tag.AcquisitionDate, VR.DT, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.AcquisitionDate));       
    attribs.setString(Tag.AcquisitionTime, VR.DT, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.AcquisitionTime));
    attribs.setString(Tag.StudyInstanceUID , VR.UI, attribsOrig.getString(Tag.StudyInstanceUID));

    //Write the file                
    attribs.setBytes(Tag.PixelData, VR.OW, b);
    DicomOutputStream dcmo = new DicomOutputStream(fileDicomFinal);
    dcmo.writeFileMetaInformation(meta);
    attribs.writeTo(dcmo);
    dcmo.close();
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Have stepped through your code and try to see where things are changing?

Comment: I try convert file jpg to file dicom. when jpg is monochrome my code is sucessful, however if the file jpg is RGB, the file dicom has colours changed regards to original image.

Comment: Where does your jpeg come from? Do you have the jai imageio codecs installed or are you using the jpeg codecs from the jre? The jpeg image writer in the ire has a defect with certain types of metadata which can corrupt the colors:  http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6243376

Comment: I don't understand your first question. "Where does your jpeg come from?"

I have installed: jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586.exe jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe and jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe

Perhaps i read the image by a incorrect way?

Comment: I don't rotate the images, i upload a sample: jpg original http://s30.postimg.org/4wh0va3w1/temp.jpg and capture of dicom http://s30.postimg.org/xamgf5rg1/dicom.jpg

Comment: The bug I referenced indicated specific issue with photos from canon cameras which had been rotated in windows.

Answer (score 0):

A color jpeg lossy file cannot be RGB. When you find one it usually has a YBRFULL colorspace (even if the color space tag wrongly specifies RGB) and you should act accordingly.

Comment: When I change this line:

 attribs.setString(Tag.PhotometricInterpretation, VR.CS, samplesPerPixel == 3 ? "RGB" : "MONOCHROME2"); 

for:

 attribs.setString(Tag.PhotometricInterpretation, VR.CS, samplesPerPixel == 3 ? "YBR_FULL_422" : "MONOCHROME2"); 

The result is a file dicom with the image covered by a pink layer :(