# Why can`t I visualize this DICOM file?

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I am trying to create a new DICOM file from a jpg + metadata

I tried this code, and I generate a final DICOM file, but when I open it I can see nothing. I am using RadiAnt DICOM viewer.

```
    BufferedImage jpg = ImageIO.read(new File("myjpg.jpg"));

    // Convert the image to a byte array

    DataBuffer buff = jpg.getData().getDataBuffer();
    DataBufferUShort buffer = new DataBufferUShort(buff.getSize());

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.getSize(); ++i)
        buffer.setElem(i, buff.getElem(i));

    short[] data = buffer.getData();
    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(2 * data.length);
    int i = 0;
    while (data.length > i) {
        byteBuf.putShort(data[i]);
        i++;
    }

    // Copy a header

    Attributes attribs = new Attributes();
    Attributes meta = new Attributes();

    //Metadatos header
    meta.setInt(Tag.FileMetaInformationGroupLength, VR.UL, data.length);
    meta.setString(Tag.TransferSyntaxUID, VR.UI, "1.2.840.10008.1.2.1");


    meta.setString(Tag.MediaStorageSOPClassUID, VR.UI, "1");
    meta.setString(Tag.SourceApplicationEntityTitle, VR.AE, "2");

    meta.setString(Tag.ImplementationClassUID, VR.UI, "3");
    meta.setString(Tag.ImplementationVersionName, VR.SH,"4");


    // Change the rows and columns
    attribs.setInt(Tag.Rows, VR.US, jpg.getHeight());
    attribs.setInt(Tag.Columns, VR.US, jpg.getWidth());
    System.out.println(byteBuf.array().length);

    // Write the file
    attribs.setBytes(Tag.PixelData, VR.OW, byteBuf.array());
    DicomOutputStream dcmo = new DicomOutputStream(new File("myDicom.dcm"));
    dcmo.writeFileMetaInformation(meta);
    attribs.writeTo(dcmo);
    dcmo.close();
```

I generate MyDicom, and I confirm that all metdata is inside but I can´t see the DICOM image.

Comment: See [How to convert JPG image to DICOM file using dcm4che-3.2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087778/how-to-convert-jpg-image-to-dicom-file-using-dcm4che-3-2-1) and [this](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che/blob/master/dcm4che-tool/dcm4che-tool-jpg2dcm/src/main/java/org/dcm4che3/tool/jpg2dcm/Jpg2Dcm.java).

Comment: I saw that code before but we are not asking for the same thing. It does another thing: jpg + metadata from a dicom file = new dicom file. What I want is jpg + metadata from the code = dicom file

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see how the buffer is obtained from the JPEG. But if the buffer is still JPEG compressed, the Transfer Syntax should be set appropriately. Supposing that you have a color image, the TS is most probably JPEG Process 1 = 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.50.

Furthermore, lots of attributes are missing for a valid DICOM file, some of them even refer to the pixel data and are definitely needed for reading it properly:

- Photometric Interpretation (0028,0004) = YBR_FULL_422
- Planar Configuration (0028,0006) = 0 (color by pixel)
- Samples per Pixel (0028,0002) = 3

(again, the values given are based on the assumption that you are writing encapsulated JPEG to the pixel data, they would look quite different for a BMP style structure of the pixel data).

Furthermore, you need at least unique identifiers for the Study Instance UID (0020,000d), Series Instance UID (0020, 000e) and SOP Instance UID (0008,0018)

The SOP Class UID (0008,0016) tells the viewer which type of image it is, you cannot go without it.

And depending from the SOP Class UID additional attribute will become mandatory. Some of them (e.g. Patient Name (0010,0010)) may be left empty ("zero length") but have to be present.

In a whole: like I mentioned earlier, you will not succeed with your task without a little basic knowledge about DICOM. DICOM is much more than just an image format. I do understand that you would like to avoid that, but it is inevitable.

Probably the type of image which is easiest to create from scratch is the Secondary Capture Image (SOP Class UID: 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.7), and [this](https://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/sc-image) page nicely helps you to gather all attributes you need to include.

Comment: thanks for that answer. is there a way to determine all mandatory attributes? when i open lets say the CT image tab, there are a whole lot of attributes. i also have some dicom files with way less attributes set, but they can still be opened with the Radiant DICOM viewer for example.

Comment: Sure but for this, reading the DICOM standard can not be avoided unfortunately. You start with an Information Object Definition (IOD), e.g. for CT image, then you look at the module table which references the modules (Patient, General Study, Image Pixel,...), and the module tables in turn reference the attributes. Simplified: Type 1=Required with value; Type 2 = Required, may be empty; Type 3 may be present but may also be missing. This is however very much simplified. DICOM is quite complex by nature.

Comment: thanks for the insight, hard to get a hold of anything when you have to read so much stuff at once... DICOM being complex by nature might be a bit of a design flaw :D

Comment: @JKreiser: That is what I thought in the beginning of my way into DICOM. But now I understand that it has a lot to do with the complexity of the matters it addresses and with precision and safety (which is a consequence of being a standard for the medical domain). Other healthcare standards like HL7 and FHIR are not really more simple